# set wpf Datagrid cell background based on datatable error

Tags: wpf, datatable, datagrid

I have an datagrid

```
      <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="304"
              Margin="0,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="790"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}"
              CanUserSortColumns="False">
  </DataGrid>
```

And somewhere in code set its content, where p_dtbl is a datatable loaded with SQL. (So I do not now what columns it may contain)

```
Me.myDataGrid.ItemsSource = Me.p_dtbl.DefaultView
```

When handeling a event (when the user enters data), I set the colError of the datable.

```
CType(Me.myDataGrid.CurrentItem, DataRowView).Row.SetColumnError(strColName, strErrorMsg)
```

How do I set the GridView cells background color to red, if their corresponding datatable cell has an error? (and back to white when there is no error)

And the tooltiptext to the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the built-in validation feature of the `DataGrid`.
And you should move your validation logic to a `ValidationRule` implementation. Although this is optional, it eliminates the need to manually track the cell's edit process in order to trigger the validation and is the recommended validation procedure. However, I will provide both examples: reporting validation errors using the `DataTable` API and reporting using a `ValidationRule`. In addition, the example also shows how to customize the error row indicator (in addition), which is an exclamation mark by default.

The `DataGrid` has the following default behavior: when a column binding reports an error, then the row header will show the exclamation mark and the cell will get a red border when in default mode. When in edit mode you can customize the appearance by assigning a corresponding cell error `Style` to the `DataGridBoundColumn.EditingElementStyle` property. When using `ValidationRule` based validation, the `DataGrid` won't allow the user to leave the cell i.e. the cell remains in edit mode until the error has been fixed.

To enable the actual error reporting, you must set the `Binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors` on the particular column to `true`.
These preparations have to be made no matter the final solution.
The solution for the row header error reporting can also be combined with both validation solutions.

### Validation using `DataTable`

First, you have to define the cell style for the error reporting:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataTableSource}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ValidationErrorCellStyle"
           TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Padding"
              Value="-2" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                 Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background"
                  Value="Red" />
          <Setter Property="Foreground"
                  Value="White" />
          <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid>
```

Next, intercept the generated columns using the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumns` event. In the handler you have to enable validation support of the binding engine and assign the validation error style.

The following example enables validation error feedback for all columns, although with the help of the event args you easily can filter the columns by index, by header and of course by column type.

```cs
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

  if (e.Column is DataGridBoundColumn boundColumn)
  {
    // Apply customized visual feedback
    var validationErrorCellStyle = dataGrid.Resources["ValidationErrorCellStyle"] as Style;
    boundColumn.EditingElementStyle = validationErrorCellStyle;

    if (boundColumn.Binding is Binding binding)
    {
      // Enable validation error reporting
      binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, calling `DataRow.SetColumnError` on the data source will trigger the `DataGrid` to give corresponding visual feedback.

### Validation using `ValidationRule` (Recommended)

First, you have to define the cell style for the error reporting:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataTableSource}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ValidationErrorCellStyle"
           TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Padding"
              Value="-2" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                 Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background"
                  Value="Red" />
          <Setter Property="Foreground"
                  Value="White" />
          <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid>
```

Next, intercept the generated columns using the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumns` event. In the handler you have to enable validation support of the binding engine and assign the validation error style.
To this point, the preparation is exactly the same.

New is the assignment of a `ValidationRule` implementation to the `Binding.ValidationRules` collection. You can create a dedicated implementation for each column or use a single implementation for all columns.

The following example enables validation error feedback for all columns, although with the help of the event args you easily can filter the columns by index, by header and of course by column type.

```cs
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;

  if (e.Column is DataGridBoundColumn boundColumn)
  {
    // Apply customized visual feedback
    var validationErrorCellStyle = dataGrid.Resources["ValidationErrorCellStyle"] as Style;
    boundColumn.EditingElementStyle = validationErrorCellStyle;

    if (boundColumn.Binding is Binding binding)
    {
      // Enable validation error reporting
      binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;

      // Register the Validationrule implementation
      var columnValidationRule = new CellValidationRule();
      binding.ValidationRules.Add(columnValidationRule);
    }
  }
}
```

Last step is to implement the `ValidationRule`. for cell data validation the input value is the actual cell value.

```cs
public class CellValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
  public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
  {
    // Check if the input value starts with '@'. 
    // If not mark as invalid.
    return value is string textInput
        && textInput.StartsWith("@", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        ? ValidationResult.ValidResult
        : new ValidationResult(false, "Input must start with '@'.");
  }
}
```

### Add row header customization

Simply define a validation error `ControlTemplate` and assign it to the `DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate` property. This template replaces the simple exclamation mark with an icon and adds a tool tip (the tool tip shows the same error message as the cell's tool tip).

The final `DataGrid` configuration for cell error and row error feedback could look as follows:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataTableSource}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ValidationErrorCellStyle"
           TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Padding"
              Value="-2" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                 Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background"
                  Value="Red" />
          <Setter Property="Foreground"
                  Value="White" />
          <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2"
            ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
        <TextBlock Text="&#xE783;"
                   FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                   FontSize="18"
                   Background="Red"
                   Foreground="White" />
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
<DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a converter that calls the `GetColumnError` method of the `DataRow`:

```
public class ErrorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataRow row = value as DataRow;
        string columnName = parameter as string;
        return row != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.GetColumnError(columnName));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` to define a custom `CellTemplate` for each column:

```
myDataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += (s, e) =>
{
    string CellStyle =
    "<Style xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"" +
    " xmlns:local=\"clr-namespace:WpfApp1;assembly=WpfApp1\" TargetType=\"DataGridCell\">" +
    "<Style.Triggers>" +
        "<DataTrigger Value=\"True\">" +
        "<DataTrigger.Binding>" +
        $"<Binding Path=\"Row\" ConverterParameter=\"{e.PropertyName}\">" +
        "<Binding.Converter>" +
        "<local:ErrorConverter />" +
        "</Binding.Converter>" +
        "</Binding>" +
        "</DataTrigger.Binding>" +
            "<Setter Property=\"Background\" Value=\"Yellow\"/>" +
        "</DataTrigger>" +
    "</Style.Triggers>" +
    "</Style>";
    e.Column.CellStyle = XamlReader.Parse(CellStyle) as Style;
};
```

Remember to change `WpfApp1` to whatever the names of your assembly and namespace are.